# Node is not serving static directory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, localhost

I'm trying to show a directory of images when the directory is added to my app's URL. Given:

```
var serveindex = require('serve-index')
  , PORT = 8888;
```

neither:

```
var userUploadedImages = __dirname + '/userUploadedImages';
app.use(userUploadedImages, serveindex('/userUploadedImages'));
```

nor:

```
var userUploadedImages = 'http://localhost:' + PORT + '/userUploadedImages'; //this would for sure be more likely to work, but i tried both
app.use(userUploadedImages, serveindex('/userUploadedImages'));
```

work. The directory of images I have does not show up, just my index which would otherwise render if I were at the root with:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('index.html');
});
```

I am using angular route, but do not have a route set up for `userUploadedImages`. I'm not getting any console errors in browser or in terminal where my server is running.

Comment: Try using the magic : `path=require('path'); var userUploadedImages = path.resolve(__dirname , '/userUploadedImages')`

Comment: userUploadedImages should be the local path, not a URL. What does the first example userUploadedImages output when you use console.log? Is it the path you expect? Note that __dirname execute in the directory the script resides in.

Comment: Are you using `express`? What is `serve-index`?

Comment: @MinusFour Yes I'm using express. [`serve-index`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-index) is the how you do middleware like this in express nowadays as it is no longer included in the main install.

Comment: @JeremyThille When I tried that and consoled it, it resolved to `/userUploadedImages`. Still didn't work.

Comment: @Kelz Right on, that's why i had that comment in the code about me sorta just taking stabs in the dark with that. I think that using localhost:+PORT is the way to go. And though that prints out looking correct in terminal, no dice in getting the directory to show up in the browser.

Comment: How about simply `userUploadedImages = "./userUploadedImages"` assuming thats the relative path to your script?

Comment: @Kelz No that doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: So there's a folder named `userUploadedImages` in the same place as your app script right? And you want to serve the listings of that folder under `/userUploadedImages` right?

Comment: @MinusFour Yes. at the top level there is _server.js_ where the script I've posted is, and there is a directory `userUploadedImages` with a couple pngs in it.

Comment: Then your first example should work, except that the arguments are wrong. The first argument to `app.use` should be `/userUploadedImages`, while the argument that `serve-index` takes should be the `userUploadedImages` variable.

Comment: @MinusFour Jesus Christ.  (－‸ლ) I just had the arguments in the wrong order. Thanks so much for your help. Please submit that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express `app.use` takes as the first argument a URI path under which the listing will be served and `serve-index` path takes a directory path to which they'll do the listings.

So in this example, it would serve the `userUploadedImages` directory in the same directory as the script file under the URL path `/userUploadedImages`:

```
var userUploadedImages = __dirname + '/userUploadedImages';
app.use('/userUploadedImages', serveindex(userUploadedImages));
```

So if you visit the server under `/userUploadedImages` you should see the listings of your `userUploadedImages` directory.